# Mobile payments on android app

Tags: java, android

Is there a mobile Payment SDK on android which doesn't need backend server for payment authorization ? What I mean is mobile only payments.
My backend is parse.com what are my options ? 
I tried searching but most mobile sdk needs backend like PayPal for instance or stripe .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're selling. If you're selling something that's strictly related to your app (which are most cases, but exceptions can be selling physical objects), you have to use Google's In App Billing system.

You can find an introduction [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html?hl=i).

If you don’t need to use Google's system, then you can use Stripe, which can be easily integrated with Parse, see [this official Parse blog post](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/build-an-e-commerce-mobile-app-on-parse-and-stripe/).

Comment: It's not object it's a service and I can't use in app billing thus looking for mobile payment alternative

Comment: @vishal I'm afraid there's no alternative if you want to publish to the PlayStore, if you use any other system your app may/will be removed as it is against Google's TOS.

Comment: Thinks this as an uber like app ! Still ?

Comment: @vishal that case is one of the exception where you don't have to use Google's system. What do you mean,  then,  that PayPal requires a backend?

Comment: Payment authorization and verification that's what they say in the document

Comment: @vishal I've updated the reply with more information.